# inverse of sum of diagonal matrix and eigendecomposition

Tags: inverse, spectral-theory, svd

I would like to simplify the following inverse computation :
$$(D + A)^{-1}$$  where $A=U\Sigma U^T$ (eigenvalue decomposition).
And D is a diagonal matrix
I know the inverse of A is  $A^{-1}=U\Sigma^{-1}U^T$. How could I expand and simplify the inverse calculation ?

Comment: I don't think that you can compute the inverse of a sum, in terms of the inverses of the two matrices.

Comment: Unless we have some additional hypothesis on $D$ and $A$ (like $D$ being a multiple of the identity matrix, or $A$ and $D$ commuting, etc), we can't really simplify this inversion.

Comment: yes, indeed, we have   $D = \lambda\boldsymbol{I}$

Comment: You should edit that into the question!

Answer (score 1):

Since $D = \lambda I = \lambda U U^\top$, we have
$$
(D+A)^{-1} = (U (\lambda I + \Sigma) U^\top)^{-1} = U (\lambda I + \Sigma)^{-1} U^\top.
$$